# Filter queryset in django templates

Tags: python, django

I have a model as followed:

```
class Venture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField()


class QuestionSet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_(u'title'), max_length=100)


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_(u'title'), max_length=255)
    qset = models.ForeignKey(QuestionSet, related_name='questions')


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers')
    responder = models.ForeignKey(User)
    venture = models.ForeignKey(Venture, related_name='answers')
    text = models.TextField(_(u'answer'), blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

There exists a set of predefined questions for all users. For each Venture, I have a page for each QuestionSet which lists the Questions in that set and I loop over the questions as followed:

```
<div> {{ venture.name }} </div>
{% for question in qset.questions.all %}
  <div class="qset-question control-group">
    {{ question.title }}
    {# How do I access the answer for the current venture? #}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The question is what is the best way to get the Answer of that Question for the current venture. I want to output some information about the answer here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't getting all `Answers` for a selected `Venture` be a smarter approach?

Comment: The problem is that I want to list all the questions and not all the questions might have an answer. Therefore some questions will be missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a custom template tage. Here is the code:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def question_answer(venture, question):
    answers = question.answers.filter(venture=venture)
    return answers[0] if answers else None
```

then used it like this:

```
{% question_answer venture question as answer %}
{{ answer }}
```

Comment: But it should be a better way to put this method to the model. Because it is model related.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to do a select on Answer for a given 'venture', which will give you a list of Answers. You can then use this to get all the questions for a venture.

So something like this:

```
ans = Answer.objects.filter(venture=v)
```

Edit::

Based on what you have said you need to rework your model. There are a number of short coming that I can see (i will let you figure it out). Else you need to do more than one query and give your view multiple query sets.

Comment: If there is no answers yet then I can't access the questions. I want to list all the questions regardless of the answers.

Comment: if a Venture can have Questions that don't have answers, then your Question model needs a "venture" FK.  (And you can remove Venture from the Answer, because it will be implied by the Question.)

Comment: The questions are similar for all the ventures. In that case I must duplicate the questions for all the ventures only with a different venture id.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

User = get_user_model()

class Venture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_(u'title'), max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class VentureQuestion(models.Model):
    venture = models.ForeignKey('Venture', related_name='questions')
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='venture_questions')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(self.venture, self.question)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('VentureQuestion', related_name='answers')
    responder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='answers')
    text = models.TextField(_(u'answer'), blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(self.responder.username, self.text)
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from example.models import Venture, VentureQuestion, Question, Answer


class AnswerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Answer
    extra = 0


class VentureQuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerInline]


admin.site.register(Venture)
admin.site.register(VentureQuestion, VentureQuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Answer)
```

That way you can have answers for each `Question` related to a `Venture`... (It sounds like that's the functionality you are looking for at least...)

```
>>> from example.models import Venture
>>> ventures = Venture.objects.all()
>>> for venture in ventures:
...     for venture_question in venture.questions.all():
...         venture_question.question.title
...
u'What is this?'
u'How does this work?'
u'Does this even work?'
>>> for venture in ventures:
...     for venture_question in venture.questions.all():
...         venture_question.question.title, [answer.text for answer in venture_question.answers.all()]
...         
(u'What is this?', [])
(u'How does this work?', [u'It just does!'])
(u'Does this even work?', [u'Sure it does...', u'I think so'])
```

and you can have another `Venture` that uses the same `Question` but has different `Answers`

```
>>> venture = Venture.objects.get(name='Another Venture')
>>> for venture_question in venture.questions.all():
...     venture_question.question.title, [answer.text for answer in venture_question.answers.all()]
...     
(u'What is this?', [])
```

after adding an `Answer` to the new `VentureQuestion`

```
>>> venture = Venture.objects.get(name='Another Venture')
>>> for venture_question in venture.questions.all():
...     venture_question.question.title, [answer.text for answer in venture_question.answers.all()]
...     
(u'What is this?', [u"It's another venture with the same question and it's own answers..."])
```